# Out of browser silverlight 4 application with local database that will run and install on windows or mac?

Tags: silverlight, sqlite

I am researching using silverlight 4 to develop a desktop application that can be installed from a browser window, now the tricky part is that I want a lightweight database embedded into the application. The database should install with the rest of the application and it should ideally work on both windows and mac systems. Originally I was thinking sqlite would be suitable for this but I have learned that it is not compatible with silverlight. Does anyone know of a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

There are some available silverlight databases such as:

1. [siaqodb](http://siaqodb.com/) - uses LINQ, available for WP7 - commercial.
2. [effiproz](http://www.effiproz.com/) - available for WP7 - commercial.
3. [Perst](http://www.mcobject.com/silverlight-demo) - open source.

These utilizes silverlight local storage, comes with their own database engine.

Comment: Careful: Perst is open source only for open source projects.  Other projects are required to purchase a commercial license.

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly a database, the upcoming release of the Sync Framework will support offline caching for Silverlight 4 on the desktop/browser, and Silverlight on Windows Phone 7.  As Liam Cavanagh mentions in this blog post before TechEd:

> I have a TechEd session this week where I will be demonstrating all of this as well as how we will be extending the capabilities of the sync framework for creating offline applications, specifically allowing Silverlight, Windows Phone 7 and even non-MSFT platforms to be used for the clients.

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sync/introducing-data-sync-service-for-sql-azure)

Answer (score 0):

There is also Ninja Database Pro that works for Silverlight and Windows Phone 7:
http://www.kellermansoftware.com/p-43-ninja-database-pro.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays SQL Lite is a viable option for SL4 / SL5.
You could also team that up with DevArt LinqConnect product (http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/) that is an EF / Linq-to-SQL like wrapper over SQL Lite.

I've also looked at alternatives Siaqo DB and Ninja DB (as mentioned by others).

Comment: "Nowadays SQL Lite is a viable option for SL4 / SL5." Is this really true? Could you point me in the right direction here, I researched a lot of (not commercial) implementations which do not work in Silverlight (because of missing ADO.Net support for instance).

Comment: @Amenti we've recently finished a large application that uses NinjaDB (vaguely based on SQLLite) for database storage on the Silverlight client (either in isolated storage or my documents if elevated permissions).
Realise that these are object databases, and does not work with an "ADO .NET" provider like you might be used to. It's rather more like Code-First Entity Framework development model. Hth.