# Silverlight database

Tags: database, silverlight, caching

I'm looking for an embedded database for a silverlight application.I have found several choices like MCObjects(www.mcobject.com) and EffiProz(www.effiproz.com). Which one is most suitable as local cache?

Comment: Have you considered LINQ to XML?

Comment: similiar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993842/out-of-browser-silverlight-4-application-with-local-database-that-will-run-and-in/2994421#2994421

Answer (score 1):

Take a look also at [siaqodb](http://siaqodb.com) it support Silverlight, Wp7, Monodroid...

Answer (score 0):

A demo of Perst for Silverlight, with complete commented source code, is available from McObject's Web site, see http://www.mcobject.com/silverlight-demo.

Answer (score 0):

Other recent Perst for .NET news - the database has been ported to Windows Phone 7, see http://mobileworld.appamundi.com/blogs/andywigley/archive/2010/06/07/perst-a-database-for-windows-phone-7-silverlight.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Ninja Database Pro also works with Silverlight and Windows Phone 7:
http://www.kellermansoftware.com/p-43-ninja-database-pro.aspx